# First-Order Predicate Logic on example

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have a question if First Order Predicate Logic always has to include quantifiers? E.g. in the sentence, A black dog bit a small child, would it be:

Bit(dog, child)

or

∀: Bit (dog, child) ?

Therefore, in the sentence All the children who live in Otley know each other, would it be:

∃: Know(x, y)

or

∃: Know (x, child) ?

Answer (score 1):

Fill in the blanks with suitable predicates.

**Example 1**

There exists x and y such that BlackDog(x) and ___________________ and ________________.

**Example 2**

For all x and y,  if OtleyChild(x) and _________________ then ___________________ and ______________________.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure, I'd say in the first Ex1 it would be 'and Child(y) and Bite(x,y)'? And in Ex2 'and know(x,y) then know(y, x)'? Is it correct?

Comment: Example 1 OK. I hadn't considered that "knowing" doesn't  necessarily work both ways in Example 2. Well done! Made edit to Example 2 for extra predicate. You still need to fill in the first one.

Comment: So bascially then the first example is ∀∀y: Child(y) ^ BlackDog(x) -> Bite(x,y)? And in the second example after the edit, would it be - "and OtleyChild(y) then know(x,y) and know(y,x)"? So ∃∃y: OtleyChild(y) -> Know(x,y) and know(y,x)?

Comment: Nope. $\forall ~\forall y: \text{Child}(y) \land \text{BlackDog}(x) \to \text{Bite}(x,y)$ says "*Every* black dog bit *every* child".  However, you want to say "*A* black dog bit *a* small child."

Comment: Oh, so it would be just ∃∃y :Child()∧BlackDog()→Bite(,)? Sorry, didn't notice this mistake. How about the other one? Is it ∃∃y: OtleyChild(y) -> Know(x,y) ^ know(y,x)?

Comment: @PaulinaPawlak For the 2nd problem, I suggested a universal quantifier. Do you see why? And you still have to say what both x and y are.

Comment: @DanChristensen As in ∃∃y: OtleyChild(y) ^ OtleyChild(x) -> Know(x,y) ^ know(y,x)? Also, I'm not sure why universal quantifier....

Comment: @PaulinaPawlak What do you make of "ALL the children..."? Not just one or some, but ALL of them?

Comment: @DanChristensen Ah, okay, I get it now, as in ∀∀y with universal quantifiers. Thank you so much for help!